# Issue with executing QSqlQuery on MySQL table in PyQt5

Tags: python, mysql, utf-8, pyqt5

I think I have begginner issue when when using PyQt5. I want to run a query on MySQL database. My query string contains international characters like "ąśćźż".

I am using `Python` 3.6.1, `MySQL` 5.7.18 and `PyQt` 5.8.2.

Part of my code:

```
db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QMYSQL")
db.setHostName("127.0.0.1")
db.setUserName("root")
db.setPassword("xxxxxx")
db.setDatabaseName("test")
db.setPort(3306)
if db.isOpen() != True:
    db.open()

query = QSqlQuery()
query.exec_("INSERT INTO table1 (id) VALUES ('ąśćźżęłó1');")
db.close()
print(query.lastError().text())
print(query.lastQuery())
```

The output:
`Incorrect string value: '\xB9\x9C\xE6\x9F\xBF\xEA...' for column 'id' at row 1 QMYSQL: Unable to execute query
INSERT INTO table1 (id) VALUES ('ąśćźżęłó1');`

Create statement of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

All character set and collation variables at mysql are set up to utf8mb4.

When I use other package than PyQt5 to connect to database - `PyMySQL`, I am not encountering the issue. In `PyMySQL` I set up connection with `charset = "utf8mb4"` as a part of connection string. I don't now how to reslove this with `QSqlDatabase`.

Can you help me with the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The hex looks lie it might be `cp1250`-encoded.  Figure out where the bytes came from, perhaps the terminal, perhaps an html form, perhaps you python.  Here are my [*notes on Python*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python); possibly the first line is the problem.  Perhaps one of the other tips is the issue.

For utf8mb4 (or utf8), `ąśćźżęłó1` should be hex `C485 C59B C487 C5BA C5BC C499 C582 C3B3 31`
For cp1250, I would expect hex `B9 9C E6 9F BF EA B3 F3 31`.

Comment: One of your tips is to ""Use MySQL Connector/Python instead of pyodbc and MySQL Connector/ODBC". 
When I use QSqlDatabase I do not see an option to set "charset" in connection. When I use other libraries like pymysql I can set up "charset" for the connection and I can successfuly work with the database. So I got not the solution, but a workaround for now.

Comment: Please provide me with the workaround code so I can update my tips.

Answer (score 0):

On sqlserver, you would need to put a U in front of your unicode character string:

Could it be the same problem ?

> query.exec_("INSERT INTO table1 (id) VALUES (N'ąśćźżęłó1');")

(edit 2017-05-02: I mistaken, N is the prefix to put)

Comment: That does not work. Usually I do not need to put anything as a prefix to insert an unicode string. After trying to put  "N" prefix I receive syntax error notification.